# Group a list of object containing a nested list of objects depending of value from another list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Two List of Objects :

`json` ListToUseForGroup.json

```
[
    {
        "type": "fabricant",
        "champ": "multivalue",
        "nom": "type_carreau",
        "l10n": {
            "fr": "Type de carreau",
            "en": "Tiles category"
        },
        "label": "Type de carreau",
        "aff_fabricant": true,
        "aff_marque": true,
        "calcul_desc": null,
        "valeurs": [
            {
                "key": "Grès pressé émaillé",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "Grès pressé non émaillé",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "Grès étiré émaillé",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "Grès non étiré émaillé",
                "l10n": null
            }
        ],
        "position": "01G",
        "groupby": true,
        "masque_saisie": null,
        "aide_saisie": null,
        "actif": true
    },
    {
        "type": "fabricant",
        "champ": "multivalue",
        "nom": "comportement_gel",
        "l10n": {
            "fr": "Comportement au gel",
            "en": "Frost resistance"
        },
        "label": "Comportement au gel",
        "aff_fabricant": true,
        "aff_marque": true,
        "calcul_desc": null,
        "valeurs": [
            {
                "key": "Satisfaisant selon essai normalisé",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "Non revendiqué",
                "l10n": null
            }
        ],
        "position": "02G",
        "groupby": true,
        "masque_saisie": null,
        "aide_saisie": null,
        "actif": true
    },
    {
        "type": "fabricant",
        "champ": "multivalue",
        "nom": "groupe_absorption",
        "l10n": {
            "fr": "Groupe absorption d’eau",
            "en": "Water absorption group"
        },
        "label": "Groupe absorption d’eau",
        "aff_fabricant": true,
        "aff_marque": true,
        "calcul_desc": null,
        "valeurs": [
            {
                "key": "BIa",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "BIb",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "BIIa",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "BIIb",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "BIII",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "AIa",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "AIb",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "AIIa",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "AIIb",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "AIII",
                "l10n": null
            }
        ],
        "position": "03G",
        "groupby": true,
        "masque_saisie": null,
        "aide_saisie": null,
        "actif": true
    },
    {
        "type": "fabricant",
        "champ": "multivalue",
        "nom": "type_pose",
        "l10n": {
            "fr": "Type de pose"
        },
        "label": "Type de pose",
        "aff_fabricant": true,
        "aff_marque": true,
        "calcul_desc": null,
        "valeurs": [
            {
                "key": "Pose sur plots",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "Pose collée ou scellée selon les dispositions des textes de mise en œuvre",
                "l10n": null
            }
        ],
        "position": "04G",
        "groupby": true,
        "masque_saisie": null,
        "aide_saisie": null,
        "actif": true
    },
    {
        "type": "fabricant",
        "champ": "multivalue",
        "nom": "glissance",
        "l10n": {
            "fr": "Glissance",
            "en": "Slip resistance"
        },
        "label": "Glissance",
        "aff_fabricant": true,
        "aff_marque": true,
        "calcul_desc": null,
        "valeurs": [
            {
                "key": "Revendiqué",
                "l10n": null
            },
            {
                "key": "Non revendiqué",
                "l10n": null
            }
        ],
        "position": "05G",
        "groupby": true,
        "masque_saisie": null,
        "aide_saisie": null,
        "actif": true
    },
    {
        "type": "fabricant",
        "champ": "simple",
        "nom": "finition",
        "l10n": {
            "fr": "Finition",
            "en": "Finish category"
        },
        "label": "Finition",
        "aff_fabricant": true,
        "aff_marque": true,
        "calcul_desc": null,
        "position": "06G",
        "groupby": true,
        "masque_saisie": null,
        "aide_saisie": null,
        "actif": true
    }
]
```

And this list of objects that I want to sort and group by using the first list

```
[
    {
        "uid": "QB32-20220325-31119",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "parent_uid": "",
        "version_application": "4.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2022-03-25T15:43:25.35Z",
        "titulaire": {
            "uid": "ETAB-00177",
            "nom": "OPERA GROUP S.R.L",
            "code_interne": null,
            "adresse": null
        },
        "gamme": "Néant",
        "serie": "GALAXY",
        "statut": "publié",
        "description": " -  -  -  - U3S P2 E3 C2 - D+",
        "caracteristiques": [
            {
                "nom": "type_pose",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Pose sur plots"
            },
            {
                "nom": "type_carreau",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Grès pressé non émaillé"
            },
            {
                "nom": "groupe_absorption",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "BIIa"
            },
            {
                "nom": "comportement_gel",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Satisfaisant selon essai normalisé"
            },
            {
                "nom": "glissance",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Revendiqué"
            },
            {
                "nom": "finition",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "Caractéristiques dimensionnelles",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Non conforme"
            },
            {
                "nom": "largeur",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "longueur",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "epaisseur",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "particularite",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Rectifié"
            },
            {
                "nom": "part_produit",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "coloris",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "classement",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "U3S P2 E3 C2"
            },
            {
                "nom": "option",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "D+"
            }
        ],
        "usines": null
    },
    {
        "uid": "QB32-20220325-31119",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "parent_uid": "",
        "version_application": "4.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2022-03-25T15:43:25.35Z",
        "titulaire": {
            "uid": "ETAB-00177",
            "nom": "OPERA GROUP S.R.L",
            "code_interne": null,
            "adresse": null
        },
        "gamme": "Néant",
        "serie": "GALAXY",
        "statut": "publié",
        "description": " -  -  -  - U3S P2 E3 C2 - D+",
        "caracteristiques": [
            {
                "nom": "type_pose",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Pose sur plots"
            },
            {
                "nom": "type_carreau",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Grès pressé non émaillé"
            },
            {
                "nom": "groupe_absorption",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "BIIa"
            },
            {
                "nom": "comportement_gel",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Satisfaisant selon essai normalisé"
            },
            {
                "nom": "glissance",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Revendiqué"
            },
            {
                "nom": "finition",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "Caractéristiques dimensionnelles",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Non conforme"
            },
            {
                "nom": "largeur",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "longueur",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "epaisseur",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "particularite",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "Rectifié"
            },
            {
                "nom": "part_produit",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "coloris",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": null
            },
            {
                "nom": "classement",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "U3S P2 E3 C2"
            },
            {
                "nom": "option",
                "label": null,
                "valeur": "D+"
            }
        ],
        "usines": null
    }
]
```

I didn't figure out how to approch this problem,
I need to loop through the first list using the "nom" of `ListToUseForGroup.json` and group by depending on the caracteristiques of the second list.

and return something like this to group them.

```
{
    "levelGroup": "type_pose"
    {
        "levelGroup": "Type de carreau"{
            "levelGroup": "comportement_gel"{
                "productObject1"{...
                },
                "levelGroup": "Groupe absorption d’eau"{
                    "productObject2"{...
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
```

The second list contain caracteristiques, I need to use that nested list to sort the principal object and do the group by using the second list.

Like you see as example `type_carreau` exist on the first list and inside caracteristiques.

Please find attached two photos to show you what i want to achieve,
I'm kind lost of how I had to approach this problem, It's quite complex

The second picture shows you exactly what I want to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to break it down to a smaller problem, just the bare minimum to implement the desired logic. As of now, it is just too much information.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Thank you for your input, that's what I did, because yes, you are completely right it's too much complicated as a whole thing, I'm trying to split it on multiple small problem.